# Related blog post in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, blogs

I use Orchard CMS. I have added a content picker field in my blog post to show the related blog post. Now I want to show this related blog post in another div out of content div. How can I do this?

Comment: There are a lot of steps to this and it requires you to have knowledge of creating alternates, editing the shapes, using the `ContentManager` class. It also depends what on what you want to show in the other div. How experienced are you with Orchard so I know what level of detail to approach this from?

Comment: I'm new to Orchard.Can U help me more?

Comment: Another approach to @devqon's solution is listed here http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/06/real-world-orchard-cmspart-7finding.html but devqon's answer is actually following the way you have started.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Placement.info of the content picker, default the content picker items are displayed in the Content area of the content item (= your current blog post).

To move the related blog posts to for example the right sidebar, just add this to your Placement.info in your module/theme:

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <!-- AsideSecond is a global zone in your theme's layout -->
        <Place Fields_ContentPicker="/AsideSecond:1"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Note the preceding forward slash, which targets a global layout zone instead of a local zone like 'Content' of the content item itself.

---

If you want to move the related blogposts to a self defined `div` **in** your content item, you can follow these steps:

1 - Create an alternate for the BlogPost content type (tip: use the [shape tracer](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools/))

2 - Add a div somewhere in that alternate (probably named something like Content-BlogPost.Detail.cshtml), and in that a local zone:

```
<div class="related-posts">
    @Display(Model.RelatedPosts)
</div>
```

3 - Alter the placement.info so that the related blogposts will display in the RelatedPosts zone:

```
<Match ContentType="BlogPost">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <!-- RelatedPosts targets the Model.RelatedPosts -->
        <Place Fields_ContentPicker="RelatedPosts:1"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Comment: Thank's for your response.I will test your solution.Can I ask a question?With this media content picker I have to select content.If I want to load this article random based on categories or tags how do I do this?

Comment: Coincidentally, @rtpHarry has placed a comment on your question with a link to someone who explains that in details